# Bayesian inference using beta distribution

Tags: self-study, bayesian, posterior, beta-distribution

A certain researcher has a Beta(2,1) prior distribution on the success rate of a new ointment. $k$ is the probability that the ointment works successfully on a patient. If the ointment is tried independently on 4 patients and works successfully on $X$ of them, what is $P(k\leq0.25|X=2)$? What is $E(k|X=2)$?

---

How might I solve this? I calculated $$f(x;\alpha,\beta) = \displaystyle\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{\int_0^1 t^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^{\beta-1}dt} \mathop{=}^{\alpha=2}_{\beta=1} \displaystyle\frac{x}{\int_0^1 t dt} = \displaystyle\frac{x}{2}$$

Comment: You computed the _prior_ density but you need the _posterior_  density.

Comment: @Xi'an Is there a formula I can use for the posterior density?

Comment: @Bing If your likelihood function is binomial, it's a conjugate model. You need to specify your likelihood.

Answer (score 5):

If you start from a prior distribution $\text{Be}(2,1)$ on a probability $k$, the update when observing $X=2$ successes out of $4$ independent trials (hence a Binomial B$(4,k)$ observation with density $f(x|k)$) is an application of `Bayes's formula`:
\begin{align*}\pi(k|X=2)&\propto\pi(k)\times f(2|k)\\&\propto k^{2-1}(1-k)^{1-1}\times {4 \choose 2}k^2(1-k)^2\\&\propto k^{4-1}(1-k)^{3-1}\end{align*}
which leads you to deduce that the posterior distribution on $k$ is a $\text{Be}(4,3)$ distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the question, I believe you're assuming a binomial likelihood, in which case this is a [conjugate model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior), and the posterior distribution is:
$$k | X \sim \operatorname{Beta}(2+X, 1+4-X).$$
The rest follows from the properties of the beta distribution:  $E(k|X=2)=\frac{4}{7}$, and $P(k \leq .25 | X=2) \approx 0.0376$.

But, as [student T](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/34623/student-t) has pointed out, to properly frame the question the likelihood needs to be specified.  If you aren't assuming a binomial likelihood, the answer will change.

Comment: No mention that each response is binomial, so you can't assume it's a conjugate model.

Comment: Well... I suppose that's possible.  However, based on the attempted work, the fact that the likelihood isn't spelled out explicitly in the question, and one of the tags is "self-study," I'm pretty sure a beta-binomial model is what the asker intended.  I would be very surprised if those weren't the model assumptions here.  Regardless, since the likelihood isn't specified, you need to assume some kind of likelihood, and binomial is certainly the most reasonable given the question phrasing.

Comment: Simply add a condition to your answer --- something like opening with "if, as seems likely, you're working with a binomial likelihood..." then Student T's complaint becomes moot. If you add a final sentence discussing other possibilities it would be a better answer but I don't think it's necessary in this case.

Comment: Good points, edited accordingly.